# why the border of thead element doesn't display in the browser?

Tags: html, css

in this code ,I set a style for border of thead element , but my problem is that the border doesn't display in the browser at all.
what should i do?,please help me.thank you.

```css
thead {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>EXAM</th>
        <th>RATE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>MATH</td>
        <td>17.50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>TOTAL</td>
        <td>17.50</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant actually add a border to the `thead` Element as that element exists but has no "physical representation" when beign rendered. `thead` and `tbody` are semantical only elements but you cant actually style them properly.

Id recommend moving the border to the `tr` childs of your `thead` and configure your tables `border-collapse` behaviour instead:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table thead tr th {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>EXAM</th>
        <th>RATE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>MATH</td>
        <td>17.50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>TOTAL</td>
        <td>17.50</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```